# Why does it seem like Syaoran likes Yukito?

Tags: cardcaptor-sakura

When Shaoran meets Yukito, he starts to feel embarrassed and blushed at his presence.

I always though he liked Sakura, but when these scenes happened I was kinda confused. Was Syaoran attracted to Yukito? If not, what caused him to feel this way?

Comment: If I remember right, this ends up covered in a later episode - there are spoilery reasons.  Divulge?

Comment: By all means, you can use the spoiler tags in you answer if you think it might be too spoilery.

Comment: The question it is not spoilery in my opinion... and the answer i don't know. But as @Krazer said you can use spoiler tags

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**It was because Syaoran was attracted by Yukito's magical power.**

It was revealed that

> Syaoran was magically attracted to the magical energies of the moon, which were residing within Yukito, as Syaoran drew his magical power from the moon.

..that was why he often blushed and feel embarrassed at Yukito's presence. It was not because he was romantically attracted to him.